# Can't set the value of a static TextField in javafx

Tags: java, exception, javafx, static, textfield

I'm working on a program for Insurance purposes and there I've a **textfield** called *Reference Key* this reference key is generated randomly every time I View the panel the other Scenes and classes needs this Reference Key , so I've made it static so that all the classes can reach this Instance directly !

My problem is that when I set the text for the **textfield** I get an Exception even from the same class that contains the instance of the **textfield**,but the shocks comes when I remove the static Keyword for the **TextField** instance it works perfectly and the text for it changes !!

My code looks like this

```
@FXML
public static TextField ReferenceKey;
.
.
.
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
ReferenceKey.setText("ABCD");
}
```

the exception that I got

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at database.project.SceneManager.LoadPanel(SceneManager.java:55)
    at database.project.HomePageController.lambda$initialize$2(HomePageController.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at database.project.CustmorInfoController.initialize(CustmorInfoController.java:100)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 37 more
```

I don't know why at the 4th line from the bottom it says

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm sure that I've imported only the Textfields for the javafx

Could someone help me please 
and thanks in Advance.

Comment: thank you @fabian you solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX does not inject components into static fields. If possible, you should pass an instance of this class around instead of using static fields. This can be accomplished by allowing methods and class using this class to take this class as a parameter. You are also able to get the controller using [`FXMLLoader#getController`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--).

However, if necessary, you can have a non-static field and set a static field on `initialize`:

```
@FXML
private TextField ReferenceKey;

public static TextField referenceKeyPublic;

...

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ClassName.referenceKeyPublic = ReferenceKey;
}
```

Comment: "If necessary". This is never necessary.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem, but could you tell me why I can't make FXML components static ?? as I read in FXML 2.2 that was allowed, but in FXML 8 that's  not.